# Is it okay to sub a 2.5" drive for a 3.5" drive in a desktop?

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, hardware

This is a hardware question in place of a Linux question. I'm fixing an older desktop for someone, which will run both Linux and Windows 10 (she needs her games, blast it). But a dual boot machine requires more disk space than her small hard drive. I can't afford to buy a 3.5" drive of a decent size, but I have some 2.5" drives I can clear. Is it fair game for me to install a 2.5" laptop drive in such a desktop? Perhaps taping it into the drive bay? Are there any issues with drive overheating or long time use? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Mind that this is going to get closed as off topic. But no taping please. Get a slider bay for it: the connectors are place in a different manner.

Comment: Technically there shouldn't be a problem doing so. You will need a 2.5"-to-3.5"-drive-adapter so that the drive fits mechanically in your desktop. Also take a look at the power- and SATA-connectors of your drive to choose the correct adapter.

Comment: I've never had a problem using the existing SATA and power connectors, even on very old desktops (with existing SATA drives).

Comment: Also, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/226290/sata-hard-disk-for-laptop-on-desktop-pc).

Comment: Also, for future reference, it seems the people voted this off-topic because you just said "linux" in your question and didn't specify Ubuntu.

Comment: @mchid nope. It is about hardware and we do not do that :)

Answer (score 4):

There are no issues using laptop drives in desktops. I have been exclusively using laptop drives on desktops with Ubuntu for many years now.

If anything, there should be less overheating because the drive is less confined in a desktop.

There is also [this similar question on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/679472/is-using-a-laptop-sata-hard-drive-in-a-desktop-risky) that has the same answer.

Just plug the smaller SATA data cable and larger power plug into the drive as shown. However, you should also properly mount the drive to the frame so that it is grounded to prevent static discharge or damage from movement.

[image: picture of laptop drive with SATA data cable and power cable unplugged]

[image: picture of laptop drive plugged into the data cable and power]

Answer (score 3):

A 3.5" 500G HDD costs less than $40 on Amazon, and that'll cost less than the appropriate hardware (3.5" to 2.5" adapter plate, and SATA power cable adapter) to mount an old used laptop drive. I won't even say what's wrong with "*taping it (a 2.5" drive) into the drive bay*".

**Ask your customer what THEY want to do.**

Comment: SATA interface *should* be identical on 3.5" and 2.5" drives. Adapter plates can be picked up for [less than a dollar](https://www.ebay.com/itm/2-5-inch-to-3-5-inch-SSD-HDD-Notebook-Hard-Disk-Drive-Plastic-Adapter-Mount-PRO/323859537381?hash=item4b67885de5:g:i0MAAOSw2FJc2WqV). In a pinch, it can be glued or left loose.

Comment: @mchid You can't plug a 3.5" drive 4-pin power cable into a 2.5" drive.

Comment: But the key here is... talk to your customer... see what they want to do...

Comment: The 4-pin power cable is molex and not SATA so it is not used at all and no adapter is needed unless the desktop doesn't fully support SATA. I was talking about the pins on the SATA power cable. The [SATA power cable has 15 pins and 3 of these are 12 volt](https://pinoutguide.com/Power/sata-power_pinout.shtml). The 12 volt SATA power cable pins are not used on the laptop hard drive so there is no risk of frying the drive from too many volts. I used to have an old sony VIAO from 2004 or 2005 that had a SATA drive that I think had a 4-pin power plug but didn't need an adapter for laptop drive.

Comment: [Here is some more discussion](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=177072) on the topic.

Comment: @mchid I **think** that we're talking about the same thing? A 3.5" SATA drive requires a 4-wire molex power plug, and a SATA data cable. To remove the 3.5" and insert a 2.5" HDD requires you to have a power adapter cable to convert from 4-wire molex power plug to something that you can plug into the back of the 2.5" HDD, along with a SATA data cable (two cables required) UNLESS you use a 1-piece 2.5" connector that has the proper pigtail(s) coming out of it (like the kind they typically use in laptops). Either example requires extra cables that you don't find in a 3.5" HDD installation. Yes?

Comment: @heynnema Actually, a 3.5" SATA drive does not require the 4-wire molex power plug if you have a 15 pin SATA power cable. You can use either the 4-wire plug *or* the SATA power cable. You can use one or the other and you don't need to use both but you can if you want to. The 4-wire plug is included on some 3.5" SATA drives for convenience and not necessity. Usually, there are two SATA plugs on a desktop setup, a small one for data and a separate plug with 15 color wires for power. Every SATA desktop (with 3.5" drives) I've seen can run a laptop drive using these two plugs with no adapter.

Comment: I know that HP and SONY desktops usually have the 15 wire and molex. There are some "notebook" drives that use smaller than 15 wire power and you would need an adapter for one of those but standard 2.5" laptop drives can use the existing 15 wire plug.

Comment: Actually, it's 5 wires, 15 pins. Orange black red black yellow.

Comment: @mchid maybe my memory is failing :-) When I have the time, I've got an old desktop that I can open up and review how it's cabled. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema Right on! I had the same deal. My SONY was set up from the factory using the 4-pin molex and I didn't even realize the SATA power plugs were there (and that I could use them instead) until I needed them to run a laptop drive. I posted some pics in the answer.